# Need to convert(Deserialize) following json into C# object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json-deserialization

How to convert(deserialize) following json format in C# object?
All this json text convert(deserialize) in one go or I need to convert child object again and again

I am trying something like this

```
var x = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json_data);
```

---

```
{  
   "Id":"1405de4d-2823-43b4-8dba-66c2714bc7f",
   "Name":"Sports/Boxing",

   "Parent":{  
      "Id":"88ada251-cff1-4eb7-bc47-2e6d366616a63",
      "Name":"http://localhost:80/PDC/Sports/Boxing",
      "DurationMilliseconds":227.2,
      "StartMilliseconds":0,
      "Children":[  
         {  
            "Id":"dbf36d18-8abd-43f1-ae9b-640cb3d77a87",
            "Name":"xx",
            "DurationMilliseconds":212,
            "Milliseconds":15.1,
           l
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you're trying?

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz perhaps, but there's no context in the original question that would make that answerable.  The question would have been closed as too broad before.  Now, thanks to the edit, it can actually be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/ and manual tuning, I've reduced the needed classes to 2 (root and childs classes are actually the same):

Note that you can give any name to your classes, what makes the link with the JSON are the `[JsonProperty("...")]` attribute above each property.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        private readonly string json = @"
{  
   ""Id"":""1405de4d-2823-43b4-8dba-66c2714bc7f"",
   ""Name"":""Sports/Boxing"",
   ""Started"":""\/Date(1472064057630)\/"",
   ""DurationMilliseconds"":227.2,
   ""MachineName"":""RED"",
   ""CustomLinks"":null,
   ""Root"":{  
      ""Id"":""88ada251-cff1-4eb7-bc47-2e6d366616a63"",
      ""Name"":""http://localhost:80/PDC/Sports/Boxing"",
      ""DurationMilliseconds"":227.2,
      ""StartMilliseconds"":0,
      ""Children"":[  
         {  
            ""Id"":""dbf36d18-8abd-43f1-ae9b-640cb3d77a87"",
            ""Name"":""Red Eagle"",
            ""DurationMilliseconds"":212,
            ""StartMilliseconds"":15.1,
            ""Children"":[  
               {  
                  ""Id"":""dbd7018d-421d-42bd-b0e5-fd3e9462cca0"",
                  ""Name"":""Blue Eagle"",
                  ""DurationMilliseconds"":106.8,
                  ""StartMilliseconds"":120.4,
                  ""Children"":[  
                     {  
                        ""Id"":""c86199e0-d12b-4bd0-90ea-9f15a2618160"",
                        ""Name"":""True Eagle"",
                        ""DurationMilliseconds"":0.3,
                        ""StartMilliseconds"":226.9,
                        ""Children"":null,
                        ""CustomTimings"":null
                     }
                  ],
                  ""CustomTimings"":null
               }
            ],
            ""CustomTimings"":null
         }
      ],
      ""CustomTimings"":null
   },
   ""ClientTimings"":null,
   ""User"":""::1"",
   ""Storage"":null
}";

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);
        }
    }

    public class Child
    {
        [JsonProperty("Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("DurationMilliseconds")]
        public double DurationMilliseconds { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("StartMilliseconds")]
        public double StartMilliseconds { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Children")]
        public Child[] Children { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("CustomTimings")]
        public object CustomTimings { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Started")]
        public DateTime Started { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("DurationMilliseconds")]
        public double DurationMilliseconds { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("MachineName")]
        public string MachineName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("CustomLinks")]
        public object CustomLinks { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Root")]
        public Child Root { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ClientTimings")]
        public object ClientTimings { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("User")]
        public string User { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Storage")]
        public object Storage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how does this answer the question at all.

Comment: OP has asked to de-serialize to an object, unless I'm mistaken he's probably looking for an object (not being a simple Dictionary).

Comment: Well though that's correct but I would say OP's question is totally unclear as in last he is asking to display that in tabular format.

Comment: That's right, actually I'm not really in a mood to down-vote or close today :)

Comment: I think there's a line missing to show how to actually call the deserializer with your class definitions...

Comment: @Aroma just added code on how to deserialize it, take a look.

Comment: Sorry, no. IMO you should stick to a POCO object, accessing dictionary keys/values is likely to become a nightmare over time :)

Comment: Thanks, yes basically the issue with generated type was `int` whereas it should be `double`. Here's another, offline generator that might do a better job : http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Aroma I've greatly enhanced my initial answer, take a look !

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. You may Deserialize (using Newtonsoft.Json) to JObject:

   ```
   var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) as JObject;

   // Then you may access properties like this: 
   var id = jsonObj ["Id"].Value<int>();
   ```

Also, there is a possibility to do traversing of this "tree" object.
More details at http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jobject.htm

2. You may generate classes out of JSON (e.g. http://json2csharp.com/) and write something like this:

   ```
   var rootObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectType>(json);
   ```

Comment: I would prefer first way for iteration. Here is how it looks: http://pastebin.com/NRxerwg0